# How to test net speed in actionscript 3.0 web application

Tags: actionscript-3, video-streaming, cdn, video-player

I made a web media player for video playing in actionscript 3.0 .
My video data are put on cdn server . I have more than 3 cdn servers. 
How can I do a test before playing video and choose the best one for user?

Now , in my project I just given a order for these cdn servers .
If there had a problem , I would change to another server.

Thanks.

Comment: Very thanks to The Mini John for the edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the easiest solution would be to load some sample file from all of the three servers, and calculate the time needed. The lowest time means the fastest speed, so just load the actual resources from there.

You might want to load a few resources, so there are few tests to compare. For example add some sample text file, an maybe few images, load them one after another (one pack of three for each server) and check the corresponding time.

Use `getTimer` for the most simple calculation of time.

Comment: Thanks, Andrey . Seems it's the only way to do that.